# Как загрузить файл на JS?

Tags: веб-программирование, ajax, javascript

UPD1. Мне нужно чтобы на машине клиента скачался json файлик, потом он обработался и выдать пользователю результат.

UPD2. Как через HTTP получить данные на машине клиента с использованием javascript.

Comment: Сформулируйте задачу верно.
Если задача стоит в подгрузке на страницу файла, например, стилей или файла скрипта, то это решение, если задача стоит в использовании input type=file, то другая.
Можно еще подумать, что Вы хотите загрузить напрямую файл, как писал @kirelagin, тогда можно использовать ActiveX (для ие и только).

Comment: мне нужно через HTTP получить данные на машину клиента с использованием javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UPD1. Мне нужно чтобы на машине клиента скачался json файлик, потом он обработался и выдать пользователю результат.

ну сначала давайте разберемся, что такое json. Предположим, что это один из видов, т.е. набор пар значение=>свойство. Еще предположим, что у Вас JSON оъект называется "test" для простоты понимания.

Тогда задача решается так:

```
var sc = document.createElement('script');

sc.src = 'путь к файлу, который отдаст json';

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(sc);

function readJson() {
   if (test) {
       // тут выполняем действия над объектом test
   } else {
       setTimeout(function() { readJson(); }, 1);
   }
}

readJson();
```

Comment: sc.src = 'путь к файлу, который отдаст json';

здесь можно указать http://localhost/example.json к примеру?

Comment: К примеру - да, если у Вас по пути http://.../something отдается json.

Comment: функция readJSON() сама себя вызывает до тех пор пока не загрузится файл?

Comment: Совсем забыл дописать строчку:

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(sc);

Без нее файл не подключится.

Comment: >функция readJSON() сама себя вызывает до тех пор пока не загрузится файл?

Именно так, стоит задержка в вызове в 1 мс, т.к. если файл не загрузится вообще (по каким-либо причинам, либо файл не отдаст нужный объект test) браузеру настанет кердык.

Comment: Спасибо за решение :-) Не знаю как браузеры устроены, но что-то вроде Stack Overflow может произойти в этой ситуации?

Comment: В данной ситуации нет, т.к. setTimeout функция вызывается 1 раз.
Этот код я написал для примера (писать здесь совсем неудобно, я бы сказал даже жутко неудобно). Но могут быть проблемы, например с тем, что условие if (test) сработает 2 раза, этого можно избежать, если написать так: myTimer = setTimeout..., а в условии if (test) первым делом грохнуть таймер так: clearTimeout(myTimer). Нужно также объявить переменную myTimer вне функции.

Comment: хорошо, применим данный способ :-)

Comment: Второй способ загрузить файл - не через тэг script, а с помощью XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите через JS загрузить себе на сервер файл с компьютера пользователя? Браузер не даст Вас этого сделать по понятным причинам ;).

Вы можете сделать на страницу обычную форму отправки файла и управлять ею через JS (ну например, делать `form.submit()`).  Но инициировать отправку файла в любом случае должен сам пользователь.

Comment: извиняюсь, но вы не поняли что я имел в виду :-)